# Make VS Code use ".js" instead of ".jsx" when auto-generating import for ".tsx" file

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, import, jsx

How do you get VS Code to use ".js" instead of ".jsx" when auto-generating import for ".tsx" file?

Given a file `foo.tsx` and `bar.tsx`, when importing bar from foo, how do you get it to say `import Bat from './bar.js';`?

Comment: Add `"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifierEnding": "js"` to your settings

Answer (score 0):

The answer turned out to be to set jsx support in the tsconfig file to "react-native" which enables auto-importing to .js instead of .jsx